# How to avoid that Del command in windows exits when path does not exist?

Tags: windows, command-line

I use del command to clean my project from objects, hex files etc.

So I use make files to collect in a list all the paths with my files to be deleted and I pass everything in del command, like this :
in make file `$(RM) $(ALL_PATHES) *.o` and this is translated in command line to this >
`del /q /path1/*.o /path2/*.o /path3/*.o`

The Problem is, that my `$(ALL_PATHES)` list is very large and some times colleges forget some paths in the list that they do not exist and then del command instead off a warning, stops with fatal error and my build is failed.

Could you have any idea, how del can throw a warning instead of error?

Comment: Try the /Q switch - e.g. del %systemroot%\System32\spool\printers\* /Q

Comment: He already has the /q switch @John .  The question is "why isn't it working?"

Comment: I missed that you tried /Q  - sorry.  Did you run the command string as Windows Administrator?

Comment: Seems like a case for a transition to PowerShell allowing to to explicitly test if a folder exists before attempting to delete it.  Outside of that have a script that is ran before your build the creates each folder that is required.

Comment: @Ramhound PowerShell is not a solution because we have to change all batch scripts. 
I cannot understand why Del does not say which folder is missing and only throws an error "path cannot find" or something similar, this is dumb. And also to check if a folder exist cost some time more in make files, it is not so fast with batch commands.